# swbemobjectex class ghost/hidden methods (eg. .Terminate)

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim objList As WbemScripting.SWbemObjectSet
Set objList = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='iexplore.exe'")
```

This code returns a collection of **SWbemObjectEx** objects
relating to all the running processes "iexplore.exe" (as seen in task manager).

I read on the web that I can run the method **.Terminate** of these objects to kill them.
However, neither the Locals window while in breakmode nor the Object Browser for the "SWbemObjectEx" class, nor the official doc at https://learn.microsoft.com/it-ch/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemobjectex, show this method **.Terminate**.

And what surprises me is that it works, although not for all the objects...

Why? and how could I see all these hidden(?) methods for this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [.Terminate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/terminate-method-in-class-win32-process) method is part of the [Win32_Process class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process). Put a breakpoint on`Call objProcess.Terminate`and add a watch on`objProcess`. That will show you  a`.Methods_`collection, where second item is`.Terminate`.

Also note the`.Properties_`collection to get infos on that process (e.g handle).

This sub prints the collections to the immediate window, just call it inside the loop through`objProcesses`, e.g.

```vb
...
For Each objProcess In objProcesses
     PrintPropertiesAndMethods objProcess
...
```

```vb
Private Sub PrintPropertiesAndMethods(Process As WbemScripting.SWbemObjectEx)
    With Process
        Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Properties_ collection:"
        Dim Prop As WbemScripting.SWbemProperty
        For Each Prop In .Properties_
            With Prop
                Debug.Print .Name & " " & .Value
            End With
        Next
        Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Methods_ collection:"
        Dim Method As WbemScripting.SWbemMethod
        For Each Method In .Methods_
            With Prop
                Debug.Print Method.Name
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

You have to be carefull when terminate`iexploror.exe`as it has a main process (x64 - C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer), that creates a child process (x86 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer) for each tab (check in task-manager). If you terminate the main process, all childs will terminate too. Too get a second main process for testing, use `Run as Admin`.

Comment: Ok but how did you arrive to the conclusion that you must look at the Win32_Process class? In the VBE Locals window, it seems that we have a objProcess object of class type SWbemObjectEx that doesn't include a method called "Terminate".  It contains a "Methods_" collection of type SWbemMethodSet, etc..., not a "Terminate" method.

Comment: That's implied by the query`select * from win32_process`! E.g. if you query for folders, you will get a different object, with different props, methods. The [SWbemObjectEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemobjectex) is just a wrapper for these objects.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub funTaskTerminate()

   Dim objTask                As Object
   Dim objProcesses           As Object
   Dim objProcess             As Object

   ' Set the object for Task Manager
   Set objTask = GetObject("winmgmts:")

   ' Set the object for all the processes in query
   Set objProcesses = objTask.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='iexplore.exe'")


   ' Loop for all processes in query
   For Each objProcess In objProcesses

      ' In my test, there were 3 processes, but the first Terminate () killed all the others, therefore,
      ' in the second Terminate () the process no longer existed,
      ' which caused an error, so the use of "Resume Next".
      '------------------------------------------
      On Error Resume Next
      Call objProcess.Terminate              ' Terminate the process
      On Error GoTo 0

   Next

   Set objTask = Nothing
   Set objProcesses = Nothing
   Set objproces = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: There is a main iexplorer process (imagepath is C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer in taskmanager and no Job object ID). if you close the all childs terminate too. Thats why first .Terminate, kills all other iexplorer, if it is main.

Comment: Yes, it's make perfect sense, because during the tests with just one tab, VBA shows two processes but I didin't think in a main process.

Thank you for


Yes, it makes perfect sense, because during tests with just one tab, VBA showed two processes, but I didn't even think about the main process.

Thanks for the clarification.